# Implication of joining tables across same db vs different db

Tags: database, sqlite, join

My program download `a.sqlite3` file in server

and `b.sqlite3` file is already in local ios.

I want to join table in downloaded `a.sqlite3` with in `b.sqlite3`

so I am thinking of copying from table in `a.sqlite3` to `b.sqlite3`
and joining the tables in the same database/

or

just joining `a.sqlite3's` table with `b.sqlite3's` table.

What is the recommended way or is there any alternative?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are you asking whether you should do joins over a database link or take the table over to the second database and do the join on one? Are you having a specific problem? What is your objective? Increase speed? Decrease network usage? This is _extremely_ database specific; please also include the RDBMS and version you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a best practice is to use the same database with multiple schemas. Each schema can be put on its own file, which can then be backed up easily if that is the reason for separation of the data across dB in the first place. A

Also you cannot have foreign key constraints across multiple databases and which is a major drawback

You may want to read up on this post http://www.unityjdbc.com/doc/multiple/multiplequery.html